# Developing .Net core in Ubuntu using VS Code

Tags: .net-core, ubuntu-20.04

I am developing a .net core console application where the application interact with SQL server for Linux,located locally, using Entity Framework Core.

When I run the application, I get the error shown below.

```
Process terminated. Couldn't find a valid ICU package installed on the system. Set the configuration flag System.Globalization.Invariant to true if you want to run with no globalization support.
```

Then I added the environment the following  export

```
export DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT=true
```

```
Unhandled exception. System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Globalization Invariant Mode is not supported.)
 ---> System.NotSupportedException: Globalization Invariant Mode is not supported.
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnectionAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnectionAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(DbContext _, Boolean result, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.SingleAsync[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable`1 asyncEnumerable, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.SingleAsync[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable`1 asyncEnumerable, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at advance_generics.part.one.Program.CountEmployees(IRepository`1 employeeRepo) in /home/bhaskar/C_Sharp_basics/advance_generics/Program.cs:line 24
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
   at advance_generics.part.one.Program.Main(String[] args) in /home/bhaskar/C_Sharp_basics/advance_generics/Program.cs:line 15
```

Can any body help me on this?

I did the  following regarding ICU

```
 dpkg --status icu-devtools
Package: icu-devtools
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: libdevel
Installed-Size: 678
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Multi-Arch: foreign
Source: icu
Version: 66.1-2ubuntu2
Replaces: icu-tools (<< 66.1-1~), libicu-dev (<< 66.1-2ubuntu2)
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14), libgcc-s1 (>= 3.0), libicu66 (>= 66.1-1~), libstdc++6 (>= 5.2)
Breaks: icu-tools (<< 66.1-1~), libicu-dev (<< 66.1-2ubuntu2)
Description: Development utilities for International Components for Unicode
 ICU is a C++ and C library that provides robust and full-featured
 Unicode and locale support. This package contains programs used to
 manipulate data files found in the ICU sources and is a dependency of
 libicu-dev.  End users would generally not need to install this package.
Homepage: http://www.icu-project.org
Original-Maintainer: Laszlo Boszormenyi (GCS) <gcs@debian.org>
```

The problem is not encountered if I run in debug or Run without debug mode I don't get the error

Comment: i get the error when i use dotnet run

Answer (score 1):

Based on the `icu` package version `66.1-2ubuntu2`, I think you are running Ubuntu 20.04.

If that's true, this an incompatibility between .NET Core and Ubuntu 20.04: https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/4360.

Really, this is a mistake by the .NET Core developers. There's not much you can do on your end to fix this. But you can apply some workarounds to avoid the issue.

The most common one seems to be the following. To emphasise, this is a **workaround**. It's probably okay, temporarily for a development environment. This is a **not a good idea for a production environment**.

```
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan main restricted'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libicu63
```

However, in my opinion, the better option is to stick to a lower version of Ubuntu, like 19.10, instead of using 20.04 that .NET Core is not compatible with.

Comment: Yes I am using Ubuntu 20,04.

Comment: Yes I am using Ubuntu 20,04. I am already using dotnet --version =>3.1.201.Talking of your work-round:sudo apt-add-repository 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan main restricted' what is the impact

Comment: Sorry, right. You need to install `libicu63`, in that case. Fixed in the answer. Adding the eoan repo basically gets you packages from 19.10. Which is not a great idea because mixing the packages from two versions is generally not tested/supported and may lead to all sorts of other issues.

Comment: Then why debugging the code gives me the same error?

Comment: Correcting my comment Then why debugging the code doesn't give me the same error?